# How to prevent loading multiple views when navigating fast with the back and forward button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a web application where the user can navigate between different pages (or 'partial views') which are loaded in with AJAX. I made it so when the user presses the back and forward button in the browser that the application returns the correct view depending on the url the adress bar contains on that moment.

My problem: When I navigate slowly by pressing the back and forward button in the browser it works like normal. But when I repeatedly press the back or forward button it loads multiple views within the application.

My question: Is there a way to prevent multiple views from loading in the application and only load the view which is supposed to load?

My Code:

```
$(window).on("popstate", function (e) {
    $(".UserNavigation li").removeClass("active");
        LoadContent.init();
    })

    var LoadContent = {
    init: function (url, query) {

        var Content = { }
        var PathName;

        if (url == null) {
            PathName = window.location.pathname;
            Content.url = "ContentArea/" + PathName;
        }    
        else {
            var Controller = "ContentArea/"
            Content.url = Controller + url
        }            

        if (query)
            Content.query = query       

        LoadContent.Loading(this);

        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Content.url,
            data: { query: Content.query, type: 0 },
            success: function (data) {  

                LoadContent.ApplyContent(data);

            },
            error: function () {

            },
            complete: function (data) {
                if (url != null)
                    LoadContent.UpdateHistory(data, url);
            }
        })
    },

    ApplyContent: function (data) {
        $("#ContentLoading").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 200, function () {
            $("#ContentLoading").addClass("hidden");
            $("#ContentArea").append(data).addClass("visible");
            LoadContent.UpdateMenu();
        })

        return this;
    },

    Loading: function () {
        $("#ContentArea").children().remove();
        $("#ContentLoading").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#ContentArea").removeClass("visible");
        $("#ContentLoading").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 200)
    },

    UpdateHistory: function (data, url) {
        var DataToSave = {
            StateURL: url,
        }

        history.pushState(DataToSave.StateURL, url, url)
    },

    UpdateMenu: function () {
        var CurrentPath = window.location.pathname;
        $(".UserNavigation li").removeClass("active");
        $("[href='" + CurrentPath + "']").parent().addClass("active");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following part

```
ApplyContent: function (data) {
    $("#ContentLoading").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 200, function () {
        $("#ContentLoading").addClass("hidden");
        $("#ContentArea").append(data).addClass("visible");
        LoadContent.UpdateMenu();
    })

    return this;
},
```

Change `.append()` into `.html()`. This will prevent the extra content from filling up more space, but completely replace the html of `#ContentArea`.

Like Parth said, you should also abort the running Ajax requests and start a new one. This won't prevent the server from sending you your results, so it's best to also cancel all old requests on the server when you're sending new ones.

Answer (score 0):

> In your case ajax response load data so what happen if you send multiple request,off course ajax data(view) replace old one.so you need to stop previous ajax request

```
 if (typeof this.xhr !== 'undefined')
       this.xhr.abort();
```

> aboove code stop previous ajax request

```
 this.xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: Content.url,
    data: { query: Content.query, type: 0 },
    success: function (data) {  

        LoadContent.ApplyContent(data);

    },
    error: function () {

    },
    complete: function (data) {
        if (url != null)
            LoadContent.UpdateHistory(data, url);
    }
})
```

Comment: I implemented this solution before the AJAX is executed so it aborts any active calls before it creates a new on, but it doesn't seem to work, I still get two views crammed in the application window.